# Should I use (non-blocking) NIO for UDP?

Tags: java, networking, udp, nio, nonblocking

According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/569555/non-blocking-udp-i-o-vs-blocking-udp-i-o-in-java), UDP just doesn't block. Are there any advantage using the (non-blocking) NIO API for UDP? Or should I just use the easier "traditional" io API?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the risk of just pointing you back, the comments to that post explain that UDP doesn't block on the TCP ACK, but you could still block on a kernel buffer overflow. This would happen only if you have a very big UDP burst.

Comment: Obviously nothing, that is exactly why you don't wait for TCP ACK.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working with a large number of streams, it may help you to have a dedicate threading model to handle those sockets.  NIO provides some of the work (selectors) that would help.

Comment: can NIO be used to listen to UDP broadcast from a server to an android phone. Is there any problem if i constantly receive and listen to UDP signals  using the traditional way in android, because in my case after working for long time its not listening to packets.

Comment: I haven't, but this post (read all responses) indicates it can be: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17472781/java-nio-udp-broadcast